# 2 outputs perceptron for "AND" logic

Tags: python, neural-network, perceptron

I've written a python script (and library) for creating neural networks, and I've tried to implement a single layer perceptron. I tested my code with a perceptron solving the following :

[image: first perceptron]

```
input     out (expected)
1.0  1.0  1            (threshold : 0,2; learning rate : 1)
1.0  0.0  -1
0.0  1.0  -1 
0.0  0.0  -1
```

and it worked (I got the expected output). But now, I want to solve the same kind of problem using a perceptron with two output cells :

[image: second perceptron]

```
1.0  1.0  1  0
1.0  0.0  0  1
0.0  1.0  0  1
0.0  0.0  0  1
```

using the same threshold/learning rate as the first time, I got only "1" outs; so i tried o mess with those, set them to 1/0.01, and this time I got (after 50 epochs, while the first perceptron finished in 9):

```
1 1 
0 1 
0 1 
0 1
```

Which is almost correct, but now I don't know what to do; my script is seemingly working, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Here is my code :
(function training a perceptron)

```
    def trainPerceptron(self, input_data, learning_rate):
        # made for a regular perceptron, not a multilayer one

    del input_data[0]
    epoch = 0
    while epoch < 50:
        # main training loop.
        hasChanged = False # witness if that epoch didn't changed anything
        for index_values in range(0, len(input_data)):
            # each line in the file (even if in this case, it's values inside an array)
            current_data = input_data[index_values]
            current_expected_out = input_data[index_values][-len(self.capas[len(self.capas) - 1].cells):]
            #current_expected_out.reverse()
            for index_cell in range(0, len(self.capas[0].cells) - 1):
                # for each cell in the input layer (except bias ones)
                # we set the activation
                if "bias" not in self.capas[0].cells[index_cell].name:
                    self.capas[0].cells[index_cell].state = float(current_data[index_cell])

            for cell in self.capas[1].cells:
                # for each cell in the output layer
                y_in = 0
                f_y = 0
                for connexion in cell.connexionsIn:
                    # we calculate the sum of the values in
                    y_in += connexion.origin.state * connexion.weight

                if y_in > cell.threshold:
                    f_y = 1
                elif cell.threshold >= y_in >= cell.threshold * -1:
                    f_y = 0
                elif y_in <= cell.threshold * -1:
                    f_y = -1

                cell.state = f_y # we finally set the state of each cell out

                if float(cell.state) != float(current_expected_out[int(cell.name[-1])]):
                    # if the result isn't the good one, we update the weight of the cell's connexions (including bias)
                    hasChanged = True

                    for connexionToCorrect in cell.connexionsIn:
                        if "bias" not in connexionToCorrect.origin.name:
                            connexionToCorrect.weight += learning_rate * float(current_expected_out[int(connexionToCorrect.destination.name[-1])]) * connexionToCorrect.origin.state
                        else:
                            connexionToCorrect.weight += learning_rate * float(current_expected_out[int(connexionToCorrect.destination.name[-1])])

        print("Epoch : " + str(epoch))
        epoch += 1
        if hasChanged is False:
            print("Solution found.")
            break
```

(function using the perceptron for a problem)

```
    def exploitPerceptron(self, input_data):
        final_data = []  # this will be the data outputted by the perceptron
    del input_data[0]  # comment this line as needed. it's needed because our data file have a useless first line

    for index_values in range(0, len(input_data)):
        # each line in the file (even if in this case, it's values inside an array)
        current_data = input_data[index_values]
        current_expected_out = input_data[index_values][-len(self.capas[len(self.capas) - 1].cells):]
        current_expected_out.reverse()
        for index_cell in range(0, len(self.capas[0].cells) - 1):
            # for each cell in the input layer (except bias ones)
            # we set the activation
            if "bias" not in self.capas[0].cells[index_cell].name:
                self.capas[0].cells[index_cell].state = float(current_data[index_cell])

        for cell in self.capas[1].cells:
            # for each cell in the output layer
            y_in = 0
            f_y = 0
            for connexion in cell.connexionsIn:
                # we calculate the sum of the values in
                y_in += connexion.origin.state * connexion.weight

            if y_in > cell.threshold:
                f_y = 1
            elif cell.threshold >= y_in >= cell.threshold * -1:
                f_y = 0
            elif y_in <= cell.threshold * -1:
                f_y = -1

            cell.state = f_y  # we finally set the state of each cell out

        result = ""
        for cell in self.capas[len(self.capas) - 1].cells:
            result += str(cell.state) + " "
        print(result)
```

and finally, the code setting the network :

```
retu = Red("perceptron")
retu.initCapas([2, 2])
retu.connectOneToAll(0)
retu.addCell(0, "bias0", 1)
retu.addCell(0, "bias1", 1)
retu.createConnexion([0, 2], [1, 0], 0)
retu.createConnexion([0, 3], [1, 1], 0)
# we have 2 neurons in + bias, and two neurons out
retu.setAllThresholdTo(1)
retu.trainPerceptron(retu.processText("and.txt"), 0.01)
retu.exploitPerceptron(retu.processText("and.txt"))
```

Comment: Can you share your code as well ?

Comment: @AnkurAnkan i just added my code :)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want **both** cell0 and cell1 in layer2 to output the AND of cell0 and cell1 in layer 1? And bias for both output cells is 0?

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist i need the cells from layer2 to output the results expected (last two columns); for instance : layer1 cell0 takes 1.0 in input, layer1 cell1takes 1.0; layer2 cell0 outputs 1, layer2 cell1 outputs 0 and so on